# Two path test in calculus

Tags: calculus, limits

Are there any tutorials,notes, etc., available online  where I can learn about the two path test. I am learning calculus, but failing to grasp the concept.

Does the following limit exist ?

$ f(x,y) = \frac{2x^{2}y}{x^4 + y^2}$

as $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$

Comment: Hint for the specific limit problem given: Consider the approach of the origin along the curves $y = kx^2$ for different values of $k$.

Comment: To come up with a curve like Michael suggested, it is often the case that bad things happen when all powers match up. Here, $y = kx^2$ gives $x^4$ for every term in the fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/Limits.aspx) are some notes with worked examples. As mentioned in the comments, try the path $y = kx^2$ for this particular example.

Comment: thanx let me check the notes